# Is it possible to pass data to Flask before render_template after Firebase login?

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I have a simple Flask function that renders a page for me:

```
@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

My question is that is it possible to pass a variable from a Javascript function which is located in my `index.html` file back to the Flask's `main_page` function before it get's fully rendered?

Here is my html file:

```
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
// HTML content
<script>
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if (firebaseUser) {
        var myVar = "content"
    } 
});
</script>
</body>
```

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    # 1. get the myVar variable from the JS code located in the same index.html page
    # 2. check the variable and pass a variable to the Jinja template based on myVar's content
    if myVar is something:
        return render_template("index.html", text = "something A")
    else:
        return render_template("index.html", text = "something B")
```

So I wouldn't like to obtain the content from textfields, I will recieve it via the JS code. I would like to load the `'/'` route once and decide what data to pass into the Jinja template based on the content of the `myVar` variable. If it's not possible, is there any trick or alternative technique that can produce almost the same results?

Comment: I think you would have to submit a POST request to the endpoint on your state change and pass it to the template

Comment: @Adam It's interesting, I have done this with textfields, when you have the rendered page then you get the content of a textfield and do something. But can't make it work while the page load. I'm afraid that it's not possible.

Comment: I actually misunderstood the question. I didn't realize it was BEFORE render and thus before it is served. I guess I'm curious as to why you don't handle the variable in the route and then pass it into the template context

Comment: @Adam Do you think about handling it with something like `@app.route('/<myvariable>')`? Like let's say var `myVar = 'myRandomVariable'; window.location.href = "myRandomVariable";` and then handle it with Flask? The `myVar` will be always different, maybe I could 301 redirect  `@app.route('/<myvariable>')` to `@app.route('/')`, but I would like to achieve it without tricking with the route. Or if you think about something else, could you please show it for me?

Comment: I'll write an answer because I think I know what you are asking now

Comment: Are you wanting 'myVar' to effectively be the default value and change on a JS event?

Comment: @Adam, 'myVar' gets its value from an SDK everytime it gets called - I would like to pass 'myVar' to Flask and use it in an if statement. And based on the if statement I would display different content on the page. So firstly I have the 'myVar', secondly I would like to pass data to the render_template method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161411/discussion-between-adam-and-rihe).

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are accessing a 3rd party API and not saving any data in your application to a database it is unnecessary to make an HTTP request back to the flask application. The state can be handled in the client simply update the HTML w/ JQuery.

```
// in callback
$('target').val('newval');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Background**: I recently ran into a similar situation as described in/by the OP. My original app used a custom *linked-based* Google sign-in service, the [App Engine Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/users). As Google is recommending users [upgrade to standalone Cloud products](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services) (rather than stay on proprietary APIs that lock you into the product), it seems [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform) would be one of those options along w/the bonus that it's based on the reliable [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/auth/docs) but [provides *additional*/useful features on top of FB Auth](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/product-comparison), so that's what I went with.

**My solution**: Like the OP, after sign-in, I was looking at how to get from the front-end JS (`onAuthStateChanged()`) to my app to switch to "logged in" mode:

- Flip login link/button to logout (or hide one & display the other)
- Display the logged-in user's name
- etc.

That's how I landed here. However, [Adam's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861438/305689) that it can all be done on the client-side w/o having to do another round-trip to your app is sound and seconded by a colleague. So I ended up doing something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var auth = firebase.auth;
var provider = new auth.XXXAuthProvider();  // pick your provider

function login() {
    auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
};

function logout() {
    auth().signOut();
};

auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user && user != null) {
        username.innerHTML = user.email;
        loginout.onclick = logout;
        loginout.innerHTML = "Logout";
        // EXTRAS
    } else {
        username.innerHTML = "user";
        loginout.onclick = login;
        loginout.innerHTML = "Login";
    }
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
Welcome, <span id="username"></span>! <button id="loginout"></button>

<!-- app content -->

<script>
var username = document.getElementById("username");
var loginout = document.getElementById("loginout");

username.innerHTML = "user";
loginout.onclick = login;
loginout.innerHTML = "Login";
</script>
</body></html>
```

If you absolutely need to hit the backend, say to check if this user is an admin, then do an Ajax/`fetch()` call in the spot where "EXTRAS" is found above. That code would look something like this:

```
user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
    fetch("/is_admin", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + idToken}
    }).then(rsp => rsp.json()).then(json => {
        if (json.admin) {
            // do admin stuff & similarly update HTML dynamically
        }
    });
});
```

Of course, your app should have the Firebase Admin SDK installed with all necessary credentials, etc. Here's what that Flask handler could look like:

```
def _is_admin(email: str) -> bool:
    # return True if 'email' is an admin else False

@app.route('/is_admin', methods=['POST'])
def is_admin():
    id_token = request.headers.get('Authorization').split().pop()
    email = auth.verify_id_token(id_token).get('email')
    return {'admin': _is_admin(email)}, 200
```